# Twig Gravatar on Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, twig, gravatar, twig-extension

I'm a newbie on Symfony and I'm having a problem to integrate the ***'ry167/twig-gravatar'*** package on my project.

First, I did :

`$ composer require ry167/twig-gravatar 3.0.0`

And after I modified my **services.yaml**, which looks like this :

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
```

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

twig.extension.gravatar:
    class: \TwigGravatar
    arguments:
        $default: ~         e.g. 'monsterid'
        $size: ~            e.g. 50
        $filterPrefix: ~    e.g. 'foo'
        $rating: ~          e.g. 'x'
        $useHttps: true
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

And finally, I have this on my view:

`<p>{{ 'example@example.com'|grAvatar }}</p>`

But I got this error:

**Invalid service "twig.extension.gravatar": class "Twig_Extension" not found while loading "TwigGravatar"**

Any ideas? I can't understand where my problem comes from...

Comment: Check your twig version.  The latest version introduced namespaces so Twig_Extension is now Twig\Extension.  You can also just look under vendor/twig and see if Twig_Extension exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably use Twig 3.* which [removed all PSR-0 classes](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/deprecated.html) (with the underscore).

The next version of `ry167/twig-gravatar` fixes the issue.
There is already a [release candidate](https://github.com/ry167/twig-gravatar/releases/tag/4.0.0-RC).

#### Option 1: Wait for next stable release

If you want to wait for the stable release, then temporarily add a `conflict` block to your `composer.json` to use the latest Twig version before 3.0:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
       ...
       "ry167/twig-gravatar": "^3.0.0",
       ... 
    },
    "conflict": {
        "twig/twig": ">=3.0"
    }
}
```

Run `composer update` afterwards to let Composer do the work of figuring out the dependencies and downgrading your Twig version.

You may remove the `conflict` when version 4.0 is released and you changed the dependency to `^4.0.0`.

#### Option 2: Use Release Candidate

If you want to use the new version right away, you have to tell composer that non-stable versions are alright using [stability flags](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability).

```
composer require ry167/twig-gravatar "^4.0.0@RC"
```

Comment: Franz, thank you for your answer!  

I understand the problem, but I'm not sure about how I should do to use this extension anyway. I've tried to change my composer to use an older version of Twig (composer req twig/twig:"^2.12"), but I still have the same error message.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Can you check which Twig version is *actually* installed? Run `composer info twig/twig`.

Comment: @CrisMenna Trying to rollback the twig version inside of a Symfony framework app will be very challenging indeed.  I would try the rc version in the answer or switch to another library.

Comment: @FranzZieris you're very kind! Thanks! The Twig version is: v3.0.1.
I'm sorry about my questions, I'm a very beginner... so I can use the rc version right now? How can I do that? I've tried running $ composer require ry167/twig-gravatar 4.0.0 but it doesn't really works (I understand that it's because it's not released).

Comment: @CrisMenna You're very welcome. I added a second option to my answer showing how to use a release candidate with composer.